# css not displaying image unless <a has spaces

Tags: css

I have a few css sprites for a rating system: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZmSz.png

When loading the thumbs

```
 .thumb-down {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZmSz.png') no-repeat -126px -13px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
 }

 .thumb-up {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZmSz.png') no-repeat -126px -33px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
 }
```

The only way I can get the thumbs to show up is if I do this:

`Was this review helpful? <a href="#" class="thumb-up rating">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> | <a href="#" class="thumb-down rating">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>`

If I remove all the `&nbsp;` then the thumbs disappear.  If I leave only one `&nbsp;` then it shows a partial view of the sprite.

How can I display the sprite without the need of `&nbsp;?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using `float:left`:

```
 .thumb-down {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qeb2b.png') no-repeat -126px -13px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
    float: left;  /* OR float:right, depending on what you need */
 }

 .thumb-up {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qeb2b.png') no-repeat -126px -33px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
    float: left;
 }
```

Comment: Using `display: block;` is superflous, as floating elements automatically are block elements.

Comment: @Guffa, I could use inline-block, but apparently IE7 doesn't like it much http://flipc.blogspot.sg/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html

Comment: @Guffa oh you are talking about a whole different stuff :s, sorry. Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the links are inline elements, you can't specify the width and height for them. They get their size only from their contents, that's why the spaces gives them size.

I think that the best option for your use is to make the links inline-block elements. That way they are block elements so that they can have a specific width and height, but they are still inline elements in the text flow so that you don't have to change your markup.

```
 .thumb-down {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qeb2b.png') no-repeat -126px -13px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
 }

 .thumb-up {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qeb2b.png') no-repeat -126px -33px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is a background. But for the background to be visible, the element must have some height and width. In your case an empty  tag has no height and width. You should make it display:block

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: inline-block;` in both of your CSS classes.